# PHP: generate unique and random numbers/ IDs

Tags: php, random

I want to generate unique and random numbers or IDs which I can use them for email verification, account reset, member invitation purposes, etc

for instance,

```
http://mywebsite.com/member/9a5af103cd540aa 
http://mywebsite.com/invite/regitration/eef0dd2e0199640 
http://mywebsite.com/reset/account/eef0dd2e0199640
```

Here I the code I plan to use, do you think it is safe and 'bullet proof'?

```
$rand = substr(hash('sha512',uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 15);
echo $rand;
```

Or any better options?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have looked into a couple of options after getting the suggestions from here:

**com_create_guid**

```
function create_guid()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
    {
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    }

    # fallback to mt_rand if php < 5 or no com_create_guid available
    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));

    //return substr(hash('sha512',uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 15);
}
```

**openssl_random_pseudo_bytes**

```
function generate_password($length = 24) {

    if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $password = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong));
        if($strong == TRUE)
            return substr($password, 0, $length); //base64 is about 33% longer, so we need to truncate the result
    }

    # fallback to mt_rand if php < 5.3 or no openssl available
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $characters .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/+'; 
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters)-1;
    $password = '';

    # select some random characters
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength)];
    }        

    return $password;
}
```

I found these two functions from php.net.

But my main concern is - are the numbers/ IDs generated by these two functions unique?

`mt_rand` - this generate randomness but not uniqueness as far as I understand - am I right?

Comment: instead of base64_encode i would use bin2hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ()` function to generate as many random bytes as you like.

Comment: Well, if you generate 32 bytes with this function I would say they will be unique enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a [GUID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) which for all intents and purposes is [unique.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: It is in the category *Windows Only Extensions*.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the purposes you list, it's by far unique enough. But I'd still check for duplicates, just to be sure. The chances are pretty small, but nonetheless, still there.