# WordPress/WooCommerce generate unique value for custom post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a solution for a client where I need to generate an incremental integer or unique string that will be inserted into multiple WooCommerce order as a custom post meta.

It's important that it's the value that is inserted into multiple orders.

I was looking at using `wp_generate_uuid4()`, but it is not unique and it would be a big task to look every order up and check if it's been used before.

UPDATE:
This has to be a separate value from the order ID, since I have to be able to generate the value, set the unique value for multiple orders.

Comment: use order id as unique ?

Comment: Although you want to use the outcome of your question for WooCommerce purposes, the answer seems more like a pure PHP solution to me [How to generate a random, unique, alphanumeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string) -- [PHP: generate unique and random numbers/ IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776553/php-generate-unique-and-random-numbers-ids)